# Rich text editor on webview for iPhone

Tags: iphone, rich-text-editor

I need to create a rich text editor (for text alignment, fonts,  bold, italics, underlining etc) for an iPhone  app.  I have heard of storing the data as HTML and rendering it in a UIWebView. I want to  allow the user to edit the data and in my app I am using TapDetectingWindow to detect touches on a UIWebView (exactly as detailed [here](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way)).

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
          tapDetectingWindow = (TapDetectingWindow *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]; //mWindow, variable reference to TapDetectingWindow
        tapDetectingWindow.viewToObserve = webView;  
        tapDetectingWindow.controllerThatObserves = self;    

        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 1900)];
        [webView setTag:1];
        [webView addSubview:keyboardText];
        [webView setDelegate:self];
        [webView setOpaque:0.0];

        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:NULL];
        [self.view  addSubview:webView];

        keyboardText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        keyboardText.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   
        [keyboardText setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addSubview:keyboardText];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But my app is crashing, with the message

```
tapDetectingWindow.viewToObserve = webView
```

and a report

```
* -[UIWindow setViewToObserve:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4a26b90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of hair pulling, here's the answer: you need to edit your AppDelegate's .m file to get the TapDetectingWindow to work properly:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController* vc = self.window.rootViewController;
    self.window = [[TapDetectingWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    return YES;    
}
```

I tried this and it's working perfectly with the rest of the [TapDetectingWindow](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) tutorial!